# How to set up NAT on the host for virtual machines in Fedora 23 with Firewalld, in order to make them visible to other devices on the network?

Tags: centos, fedora, kvm, firewalld

- Host: Fedora 23
- Guest: CentOS 7.0
- KVM/QEMU

Here is what I am trying to do.
Set up NAT on the host system (Fedora 23) so that the guest (CentOS 7.0) would be visible from outside (by other devices connected to the same router)
And then I intend to set up NAT on the router so that this guest machine would be visible to the world. In the following sense: 
When you type in the public IP that has been assigned to my router in your web browser you can access the web server running on the CentOS machine.
And I would really like to use firewalld for this configuration on the host.

Here is what I have tried:

- Host:192.168.1.137 : Zone public : masquerading on : interface enp9s0
- Guest: 192.168.122.10 interface vibr0 port 80 is opened

---

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 => /etc/sysctl.conf 

sysctl -p

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=192.168.122.10
```

When I make a request via web browser to `192.168.1.137`(HOST) form my phone on the same network I cannot reach the web server running on `192.168.122.10`

Note:
I do understand that I am probably doing something extremely stupid, and I am kinda stuck, been going over the `firewall-cmd` command line documentation but it seams to be lacking in terms of examples for the NAT setup.

Or if you could tell me if I am wasting my time with `firewalld` and should just revert to `iptables`?